# normalize data and it's impact on error of prediction

Tags: machine-learning

could anyone tell me what is the impact of normalization on absolute error and root mean square error? as a matter of truth, I used normalize data and allso un-normalized data for regression by random forest algorithm, the result (absolute error and RMSE) differ significently!! for example(with normalized data: Absolute error=0.1014 and RMSE=0.173 BUT with UnNormalized data: Absolute error=4.419 and RMES=7.57)
I'm wondering about these significant difference between normalized and unNormalized cases!
any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I found that it's because of the range of data in normalize and un-normalize form.